How to get a translated month name with date
I have a date in this format:  2024-05-18.
I want to get day-month-year format so i used
<?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->data, 'php:d F Y') ?>

And i get : 18 May 2024
How can i get the month in Italian?
I tried to add this inside my config.php
'formatter' => [
            'locale' => 'it-IT',
            'language' => 'it-IT',
            'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
            'timeZone' => 'Europe/Rome',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
        ],  

But it doesn't Work.

Configuration 'locale' => 'it-IT' should do the trick. Are you sure it-IT locale is available in environment where you are running the app?

I voted up, but just to direct to the right point: Check your php.ini file to set the right config for your environment

I try dd(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT')) and i get false, if i use en_EN i get false en_EN

Does your php installation have intl extension enabled? Formatter tries to use intl extension to format dates but it fall back to DateTime::format() if intl is not available. The locale configuration is only available with intl. You need to use setlocale with DateTime fallback. I would suggest enabling intl extension if possible. Your attempt with setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT') was correct but returned false means the it_IT locale is not available in host system. There is no en_EN locale, try en_US or en_GB instead.

On linux systems you can get list of all available system locales by running locale -a command in shell.
